# Represent Adobe's array-like collections in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, collections, typing

Adobe's ExtendScript features `Number`-indexed collections, for example the `ArtLayers` type. `document.artLayers[0]` might get me the first `ArtLayer` in the present document. `ArtLayers` also has a number of miscellaneous fields and methods. How can I best represent this type in a `.d.ts` file?

Answer (score 3):

A definition for `ExtendScript` can already be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/photoshop.d.ts). I looked at it and it does not seem perfect, but it could be a starting/reference point.

If I had to write a type as you describe it,  I would probably use something like this:

```
interface ArtLayers {
    length: number;
    [index: number]: ArtLayer;
    parent: Document
    typename: string
    add(): void
    getByName(name: string): void
    removeAll(): void
}
```

Comment: FYI, the package `photoshop.d.ts` does not implement array-like access on `ArtLayers`, or AFAIK on any array-like ExtendScript type.

Comment: @CarlPatenaudePoulin Yeah I saw, kind of a bad definition, but like I said, it may be a good enough start. You could take those definitions and extend the using interface merging with what is missing

Comment: Extendscript doesn't always behave like Javascript.  The problem here is that normal Javascript doesn't offer index-operator overloading, but Extendscript uses it for some of their types, so you can't have a perfect definition for Typescript.  When I was working on my own [definition file](https://github.com/timmythetiny/adobe-typings/blob/master/definitions/photoshop.d.ts), I tried to get around the issue by building in functions that would return the indexable types as arrays.  I'll be curious to see what solution you come up with.